# How to create new user in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I created the model:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ClientModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $connection = 'local_db';
    protected $table      = 'administrators';
    protected $fillable   = ['user_id'];

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
ClientModel::create(array(
    'username' => 'first_user',
    'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
    'email'    => 'my@email.com'
));
```

It creates empty entry in DB...

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `create` method (Mass Assignment) so it's not working because you have this:

```
// Only user_id is allowed to insert by create method
protected $fillable = ['user_id'];
```

Put this in your model instead of `$fillable`:

```
// Allow any field to be inserted
protected $guarded = [];
```

Also you may use the alternative:

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'email'];
```

Read more about [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) on `Laravel` website. While this may solve the issue but be aware of it. You may use this approach instead:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'jhondoe';
// Set other fields ...
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 24):

I think you make it too complicated. There is no need to make it this way. By default you have `User` model created and you should be able simple to create user this way:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'something';
$user->password = Hash::make('userpassword');
$user->email = 'useremail@something.com';
$user->save();
```

Maybe you wanted to achieve something more but I don't understand what you use so many methods here if you don't modify input or output here.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays way :

```
User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

or even:

```
        $arrLcl = [];
        $arrLcl['name'] = $data['name'];
        $arrLcl['email'] = $data['email'];
        $arrLcl['password'] = $data['password'];
        User::create($arrLcl);
```